# Every compact subset of an open convex set $B\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ can be covered by finitely many cubes

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Consider the following statement:

> Every **compact** subset of an **open convex** set $B\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ can be
>   covered by finitely many **cubes** having edges parallel to the coordinate
>   directions $e_1,...,e_k$.

How is the statement translated for the case $k=1$? And what's the relation with the fact that "*There are many compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are not the union of finitely many closed intervals*'' as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166206/compact-subsets-of-the-real-numbers)?

Comment: There is a difference between being *covered*, which would only mean $B\subseteq \bigcup K_i$ and being the union of sets, which is $B=\bigcup K_i$.

Comment: In the case $k=1$, rectangles are just closed intervals. Being covered by is not the same as being the union of. Being covered by means being *contained* in the union of finitely many rectangles.